# add "shipping method (carrier)" column to csv file

Tags: magento-1.9

when I export shipments on Magento admin ( Sales > Shipments > export (to csv) ) I'd like to export Shipping method(carrier) too.
How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
Just need to change prepareCollection funcion with the below code:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('shipping_method'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

and after that add a column for shipping method:

```
$this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
        'index' => 'shipping_method',
    ));
```

Now try exporting the csv.